# MySQL wildcard replace

Tags: mysql, replace, wildcard, placeholder

Hi i need help with a MySQL query.
Is it possible to do some wildcard replace for a string like the example below?

String:                        **example.com/folderone**/some/path/to/file.pdf 
String:                        **example.com/foldertwo**/some/path/to/file.pdf 
Replace: **newsite.com**/some/path/to/file.pdf

newsite.com/some/path/to/file.pdf
newsite.com/some/path/to/file.pdf

To remove the folder and change the domain but keep the path. In this case each folder have a **different name** with a **different length**.

something like:

```
update TABLE set COLUMN = replace(COLUMN, 'example.com/%/', 'newsite.com/');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET column1 = REPLACE(
         column1, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '/', 2),
         'newsite.com' 
       )
 WHERE column1 LIKE 'example.com/%/'
```

This should honour your subfolder structure.