# how to remove part of string from all values

Tags: mysql

I have many image URLs stored in **url** column. I want to replace all urls like this one

```
/photobook/20766/725714/image_20766_11_2017-04-29 10:17:27 +0000.jpg
```

to become

```
/photobook/20766/725714/image.jpg
```

so mainly, I want all images to have "image.jpg" name.
**Note**: this part

> /photobook/20766/725714/

change from row to row. So how I could do that ?

Comment: `I want all images to have "image.jpg" name`, what if there is stored `png` image for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL wildcard replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728060/mysql-wildcard-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '/image', 1),  -- everything before /image
                 '/image.',                          -- add /image.
                 SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '.', -1))      -- add the file extension
WHERE col LIKE '%/image_%'
```

Follow the link below for a demo showing that the string manipulation logic is working correctly.

## Rextester